# Stream key with YASEA

Tags: java, android, stream, rtmp

I'm trying to stream via RTMP to a server made by other people. I'm using Android so I'm trying with YASEA.

I've used YASEA other times and it worked good, just passing and URL to it. My problem now is that the server now has an url type:

> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]

but also I have what they call "Stream Name/Stream Key".

I've tested OBS and the Android app RTMPCamera and they let me set url and that Stream key, but in YASEA I don't have a clue of where to put that key.

Does anyone know if there's a place to set it or if I can set it within the URL?

I've tested with:

> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]/[key]
>
> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]?StreamKey=[key]
>
> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]?StreamName=[key]
>
> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something][key]
>
> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]?key=[key]
>
> rtmp:[server]:[port]/[something]/[something]?[key]

But none of those worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.. usually it's just url/stream_key.

rtmp:[server]:[port]/["Stream Name/Stream Key"]